# Retrieve last item in Session::

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I was wondering how i could retrieve the last instance in the Session named smartBacklinks.

**Here is the code**

```
if(Session::has('smartBacklinks'))
{
    // if(Request::header('referer') === LAST ITEM IN SESSION[smartBacklinks] ARRAY)
    Session::push('smartBacklinks', Request::header('referer'));
}
else
{
    Session::put('smartBacklinks', [Request::header('referer')]);
}
```

Also how do i retrieve this from a blade template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my code alot and it is now functioning. I still need to add a few tweaks to make it behave 100% as i need it

The code looks like this right now:

```
if(Session::has('smartBacklinks')){
    // Get the last item in Session array 
    $slice = array_slice(Session::get('smartBacklinks'), -1, 1);

    // Check if Request::header('referer') is equal to the $slide[0]
    if(Request::header('referer') != $slice[0]){
        // Check if Request::header('referer') is empty
        if(Request::header('referer') != '') Session::push('smartBacklinks', Request::header('referer'));
    }
    // If session[smartBacklinks] is not set. - Set
    }else {
        Session::put('smartBacklinks', [Request::header('referer')]);

        $slice = array_slice(Session::get('smartBacklinks'), -1, 1);
    }

Session::save();
```

Then of course the last instance of the session array is

```
$slice[0]
```

The last thing i need to add is:

- when "back button" is clicked, it should remove the last instance of the session array, and it should not push URL into the session
- I need to make sure that the session is loaded correctly so i dont have to refresh the webpage to get the correct "back URL"

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve 'smartBacklinks' from the session based on the key like so:

```
$value = Session::get('smartBacklinks');
```

Also, you may want to note that you'd use `Session::push()` for pushing into an array session value and use `Session::put()` to simply store an item in session.

Retrieving the value from blade:

I guess you could pass the variable just retrieved to the view from the controller like so:

```
return View::make('foo.bar', array('smartBacklinks' => $value));
```

then use it in blade like so:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to($smartBacklinks) }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary">Go back</a>
```

Hope that helps.